# How do I display multiple webcam feeds side by side using OpenCV Beta 3.0.0 and Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, webcam, video-capture

I am working on a project that requires that I display 3 (and possibly more) webcam feeds side by side. To tackle this project, I am using OpenCV Beta 3.0.0 and Python 2.7.5 because I am slightly familiar with the language. Also, how do I display the video in color?

Here is my current code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
capture1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:
    ret, frame = capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow("frame",gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
capture1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:
    _, frame1 = capture.read()
    _, frame2 = capture1.read()
    frame1 = cv2.cvtColor(frame1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    frame2 = cv2.cvtColor(frame2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    cv2.imshow("frame1",frame1)
    cv2.imshow("frame2",frame2)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
capture1.release()
capture2.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

To display color you simply don't convert to grayscale. To show two frames simultaneously just call `imshow()` twice. As for side by side, you can play with the frame positions if you really want. Also notice that the I converted the frames from BGR to RGB.

Comment: Thanks! It works great! How would I not convert the color at all?

Comment: just comment out the lines `frame1 = ...` and `frame2 = ...`. if you're struggling to understand this code please familiarise yourself with python/opencv a bit before doing more advanced things!

Comment: could you please accept the question so it can be closed?

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't thinking when I asked that! :) I got it working the way I wanted it to! :)